# Where to start to build .NET Multiuser Chat Application?

Tags: .net, chat, multi-user

Which .NET namespaces should I be looking at if I'd like to start writing a very simple chat application (in C#)?

Please let me know if there's a way that I can clarify or expand on this to make it a more precise question.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to need to look at System.Net, System.Net.Sockets, and System.Threading.  To get a basic idea of how to send messages through TCP connections please refer to the following url: [Simple Threaded TCP Server](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server)

Answer (score 0):

For just the basic functionality:

[System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.aspx)
[System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets%28VS.71%29.aspx)

The TcpClient class will be your friend.

[TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28VS.71%29.aspx)

If you are going to do advanced things like file transfers:

[System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx)